# Setting window.location in JavaScript hangs

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, fiddler

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. My app uses jQuery on the client side. The user can enter values into several fields and click "Refresh". The Refresh is behaving oddly.

When Refresh is clicked, I execute the following JavaScript:

```
function refresh() {
    var chosen = "(someField eq 'value')";
    try {
        if (chosen) {
            var url = 'http://localhost:8089/item&c=' + chosen;
            alert(url);
            window.location = url;
        } else {
            window.location = 'http://localhost:8089/item';
        }
        return false;
    } catch (ex1) {
        alert(ex1);
    }
}
```

The value for `chosen` is actually generated via a function. I've noticed when I use a certain type of control, the page hangs. Here is what is odd, I can see the request made in Fiddler. Yet, my breakpoint in my controller action is never hit. If I copy and paste the url from the `alert` call into the address bar, my breakpoint gets successfully hit. So, I'm totally confused.

1. Due to the fact this involves a specific control, I at first assumed this was a JavaScript error. However, I do not see any JavaScript error in the console. I also checked to see if any exceptions were being swallowed and I did not see any.
2. The fact I see the request in Fiddler, would imply that I'm getting to the web server. Yet, if I have a breakpoint on the very first line of the controller action, I would expected that to trip. It does not trip in the scenario where I use the control. It does trip if I do NOT use the control. The result in Fiddler sits at '-'. It never returns. Plus, I do not get an exception thrown in my ASP.NET view.

I'm totally stuck on this and looking for ideas of potential causes. Thank you.

Comment: running this code from the chrome console redirects just fine

Comment: Which browser are you using to test this?

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue in Chrome and IE 11.

Comment: Discovered it only happens when I use the `remote` option for the bloodhound suggestion engine in typeahead.js. I do not have a fix yet though.

Comment: Don't hard code your url's like that (what happens when you publish this to another server?). Use `var url ='@Url.Action(....)';`

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is usually the result of a problem during model binding for the controller.

A quick step to try is making sure the query string values you are sending are properly encoded.

`var chosen = "(someField eq 'value')";
chosen = encodeURIComponent(chosen);`

Would eliminate any bad character problems that the model binder might be having.